# Build array from json output getting from javaservice in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to build following output from input json.

Input:-

```
{"@CreateRef":"test","@MsgVer":"1.0","@RegionalUnits":"Metric","@TimeZone":"UTC","MsgID":"b53beeba-b494-4a98-a4b8-69708607863c","MsgTimeStamp":"2013-12-06T05:36:12.200Z","MsgStatus":{"ResponseCode":"0","ResponseText":"OK"},"Items":{"Item":[{"ItemID":"6CB85786-9265-4A77-B367-0E9F57659423","ItemName":"Vegetables","ItemParentID":"Null"},{"ItemID":"BCB1B119-03DD-4229-B33A-B7C15BF56423","ItemName":"Veg1","ItemParentID":"6CB85786-9265-4A77-B367-0E9F57659423"},{"ItemID":"5D46FECC-9BF1-437C-AC3F-9F70B1830E53","ItemName":"Veg2","ItemParentID":"6CB85786-9265-4A77-B367-0E9F57659423"},{"ItemID":"382E8D71-6A89-40FF-8F51-7516CDBD88C3","ItemName":"Fruits","ItemParentID": "Null"},{"ItemID":"1E992DC7-AF45-447C-A61A-1CA3E52B756B","ItemName":"Fruit1","ItemParentID":"382E8D71-6A89-40FF-8F51-7516CDBD88C3"},{"ItemID":"B335CCBC-A2EA-4E9C-BD15-59E449AB34FA","ItemName":"Fruit2","ItemParentID":"382E8D71-6A89-40FF-8F51-7516CDBD88C3"}]}}
```

This json has parent and child relationship like as follows:-

Vegetables(Parent) -> Veg1(child1) and Veg2(child2)
Fruits(Parent)-> Fruit1(child1) and Fruit2(child2).

***Need following output:-***

```
testmenus = [
    {
        key: 'Vegetables',
        items: [
    { name: "Veg1" },
    { name: "Veg2" }
    ]
    },
    {
        key: 'Fruits',
        items: [
    { name: "Fruit1" },
    { name: "Fruit2" }
    ]


    }
    ];
```

How to get above output in **JQuery** only because we are going to do this process in jquery mobile app.

Please help in this regard.

Comment: try with `Gson` library for java.

Comment: Need to get this output through Jquery only.

Answer (score 0):

you can use parseJSON() function to get object or array from json string

follow link:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: I tried "underscore.js" above method. But it is throwing following error. "ReferenceError: _ is not defined'" what is problem.

Comment: Also I tried  testmenus = jQuery.parseJSON('[' + temp + ']'); where temp contains json. It is throwing "Error: 'SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character'" what is problem

Comment: why do you add brackets to your json string, please remove and try again

Comment: We are getting json object directly(no need to parsejson) from live service. Now we need to create like above "Need following output:-" type in jquery instead of underscore.js.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/2fkH5/) using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) (that's a utility-belt library for JavaScript).

```
var temp = /* input JSON */
output= [];
var parent = _.filter(temp.Items.Item, function(d){return d.ItemParentID == "Null";});
_.each(parent, function(d){output.push({"key":d.ItemName, items: [], id: d.ItemID});});
_.each(temp.Items.Item, function(d,i){
  if(d.ItemParentID != "Null") {
    _.find(output, function(d1){
      return d1.id == d.ItemParentID;
    }).items.push({"name":d.ItemName});
  }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

See, if you can use this or convert this into pure jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

What i can suggest you is to do with `jQuery.parseJSON()`:

```
testmenus = jQuery.parseJSON('['+ yourdataVARfromjavaservice +']');
```